# Git , Merge Already Up TO date but with diff?

Tags: git, csv, merge, diff

I have two local branches, say A and B.
I run the following commands

1. git checkout A
2. git merge -X theirs B - "comment"

if i run again the command
git merge B  --> it throws the message "Already up to date"

if i run the follow command
git diff A..B   --> it returns differences in 4 files

So I "smash" the content of branch A with the content of branch B
if i run again the merge command on branch A it returns that everything is up to date
but if i run the "diff" between the two branches it return differences in four files.

What is happening ?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to know:

- Git traffics in *commits*.
- Every commit has at least one parent, and "reaches" other commits by means of its chain of parents.
- A branch is a name for *one commit*.
- Merging creates a commit and moves the branch name of the *current* branch.
- The phrase "up to date" means that one branch doesn't reach any commits that the other branch doesn't reach.

So let's say we start with this situation (arrow point backwards in time, each commit pointing at its parent):

```
A <-- B <-- C <-- D (branch1)
 ↖︎
   <-- X <-- Y <-- Z (branch2)
```

Now I checkout `branch1` and say `git merge branch2`. I get this:

```
A <-- B <-- C <-- D <-- M (branch1)
 ↖︎                    ↙︎
   <-- X <-- Y <-- Z (branch2)
```

So now, on the one hand, there is no point trying to merge `branch2` into `branch1` *again*; `branch1` already reaches all the same commits that `branch2` reaches. Hence, "up to date". But commit `M` and commit `Z` are not identical to one another either.

---

Perhaps your confusion is because you think

```
git merge -X theirs B
```

does something special with regard to a merge. It doesn't. This is still a perfectly ordinary merge. The only thing it does specially is in case there happen to be any merge conflicts; the `theirs` provides a hint about how to resolve those conflicts without asking for human help.

Comment: An important note about `-X` [highlighted on the manual page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_merge_strategies) is that it doesn't select a merge *strategy*, it selects an *option for the selected strategy*. So on its own, `-X theirs` uses the "recursive" strategy with the "theirs" option, which as you say controls how conflicts are resolved. Their is also an "ours" *strategy* (`-s ours`), which marks everything as merged without pulling in any changes from the other branch (there's no "theirs" strategy, though).

Comment: Yes, I purposely omitted the `ours` strategy. It isn't really relevant, because it wouldn't make `M` identical to `Z` either.

Comment: It could be used to create a tree where M and Z were the same, I think, by making the merge on branch2 and then swapping the pointers around. Something like `git switch branch2; git merge -s ours branch1; git branch temp; git reset --hard HEAD^; git switch branch1; git reset --hard temp; git branch -d temp` At the end, branch1 would have the content of branch2 (commit Z), but an extra parent of commit D.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer , i open one of the files that the diff says it is different and there are really different , how can i "smash" the version of A with the version in B ?what i want to do is to "smash" all the content in branch A with the content in branch B, like a "replace" ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok but that is _not what you asked_. I have tried to answer the question you asked. If you have a different "how to" question, perhaps you could ask it as a new question. Though I think an earlier comment does answer that.

Comment: Or if you don't care about the loss of history, don't merge; just replace one branch with the other.